# Why not call DllEntryPoint in C++ Builder?

Tags: winapi, dll, c++builder, c++builder-10-seattle

I've create DLL project in RAD studio Seatle C++ Builder and I've checked checkbox that "link with runtime packages" and added to Project Options -> C++ Linker -> Additional options "midas.lib"

"Runtime package import libraries" of DLL project like that.

> adortl;appanalytics;bcbie;bcbsmp;bindcomp;bindcompdbx;bindcompfmx;bindcompvcl;bindengine;CloudService;compont1;compont4;CustomIPTransport;DataSnapClient;DataSnapCommon;DataSnapConnectors;DatasnapConnectorsFreePascal;DataSnapFireDAC;DataSnapIndy10ServerTransport;DataSnapNativeClient;DataSnapProviderClient;DataSnapServer;DataSnapServerMidas;dbexpress;dbrtl;dbxcds;DbxClientDriver;DbxCommonDriver;DBXDb2Driver;DBXFirebirdDriver;DBXInformixDriver;DBXInterBaseDriver;DBXMSSQLDriver;DBXMySQLDriver;DBXOdbcDriver;DBXOracleDriver;DBXSqliteDriver;DBXSybaseASADriver;DBXSybaseASEDriver;dsnap;dsnapcon;dsnapxml;emsclient;emsclientfiredac;FireDAC;FireDACADSDriver;FireDACASADriver;FireDACCommon;FireDACCommonDriver;FireDACDb2Driver;FireDACDBXDriver;FireDACDSDriver;FireDACIBDriver;FireDACInfxDriver;FireDACMongoDBDriver;FireDACMSAccDriver;FireDACMSSQLDriver;FireDACMySQLDriver;FireDACODBCDriver;FireDACOracleDriver;FireDACPgDriver;FireDACSqliteDriver;FireDACTDataDriver;fmx;fmxase;fmxdae;fmxFireDAC;fmxobj;FMXTee;FmxTeeUI;GifImagePack;ibmonitor;ibxbindings;ibxpress;IndyCore;IndyIPClient;IndyIPCommon;IndyIPServer;IndyProtocols;IndySystem;inet;inetdb;inetdbxpress;Intraweb;Package5;RESTBackendComponents;RESTComponents;rtl;soapmidas;soaprtl;soapserver;svn;Tee;TeeDB;TeeUI;tethering;TGrfButton;Utils;vcl;vclactnband;vcldb;vcldsnap;vclFireDAC;vclib;vclie;vclimg;VCLRESTComponents;vclribbon;VclSmp;vcltouch;vclwinx;vclx;xmlrtl

I'm loading this DLL in EXE like that.

```
LoadLibrary(L"MyDll.dll");
```

When I debuging DLL,DllEntryPoint method is not called.

```
int WINAPI DllEntryPoint(HINSTANCE hinst, unsigned long reason, void* lpReserved)
{
    return 1;
}
```

**when I removed midas.lib or any .lib DllEntryPoint is called.**

I don't understand different

any idea ?

Comment: Could it be, that your DLL entry function is set up to be `DllMain` ?

Comment: A very rough guess is that midas.lib is actually a static library and not an import library.  And that it contains a DllEntryPoint function as well.  Given the choice between two, the linker picks whichever it encounters first.  Not easy to fix.

Comment: When I added adortl.lib to "Additional options" calling DllEntryPoint.
But if I added midas.lib not calling. I don't understand relation between adortl and midas.

Comment: Midas.lib is likely an import lib for midas.dll. If you link to midas.dll, you have to deploy it with your DLL or else LoadLibrary() will fail to load your DLL into memory before DllEntryPount() can be called. If you don't want to deploy midas.dll, you have to static link the entire midas library into your DLL, by linking to midaslib.dcu. Search on Google for how to do that in C++Builder, there are solutions available.

Comment: thank you @RemyLebeau for detail response.
I understood source of problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

midas.lib has no need to add.Because dsnap has already been added.
[image]

I removed midas.lib from Additional options(C++ Linker)